# Custom citation in list of tables

Tags: captions

The problem i have right now is that, i need to use different citation in list of figures and text as latex thinks the citation i have in list of figures comes first and numbers it like that. Hence i am trying to use short option with line;

```
\caption[Molecular simulation cell$\left[x\right]$]{Molecular simulation cell\cite{sim1}}
```

Which produces ;

Figure 1.2 : Molecular simulation cell[x .............................................................. 2

Instead of;

Figure 1.2 : Molecular simulation cell[x] .............................................................. 2

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `[Molecular simulation cell {[x]}]` . You don't need `$` there unless `x` is a math parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When LaTeX sees `\caption[`, it looks out for the next closing bracket `]`, without counting up and down nested `[` and `]` (and reasonably so: the computer cannot be sure you mean each inner `[` to be matched by a `]`). One possibly solution is:

```
\def\braright{\right]}
\caption[Molecular simulation cell$\left[x\braright$]{Molecular simulation cell\cite{sim1}}
```

If you have a sense for symmetry, you will of course also define `\braleft`.

For a more idiomatic solution, see the comments by Harish Kumar and Sean Allred.

Comment: The idiomatic solution is to 'hide' the brackets you don't want LaTeX to see as it's scanning: `\caption[I see these characters as one token each but {this entire group[ is ] counted as one} and back to normal]{blah}`.